# Slurm heterogeneous job groups are holding onto the entire allocation

Tags: slurm

I'm launching a [heterogenous job group](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html) in slurm where my slurms script looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
srun --pack-group 0 short-process &
srun --pack-group 1 long-process &
wait
```

And my sbatch submission looks something like:

sbatch --mem-per-cpu=4g --ntasks=1 : --mem-per-cpu=2g --ntasks 1 mybash.sh

I'd hoped that when short-process was done it would release its allocation, but when I run sacct I see that both pack groups are listed as running, although the first run step for pack-group 0 is listed as COMPLETE.

Is there a way to get short-process to release the slurs allocation when it is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it explicitly with `scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID+0` to cancel pack-group 0 for instance.

```
#!/bin/bash
{ srun --pack-group 0 short-process ; scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID+0 ; } &
srun --pack-group 1 long-process &
wait
```